# How do I set up a live audio streaming http server?

Tags: http, html5-audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I was hoping to build an application that streams audio (mp3, ogg, etc.) from my microphone to a web browser.

I think I can use the html5 audio tag to read/play the stream from my server.

The area I'm really stuck on is how to setup the streaming http endpoint. What technologies will I need, and how should my server be structured to get the live audio from my mic and accessible from my server?

For example, for streaming mp3, do I constantly respond with mp3 frames as they are recorded?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

First off, let's split this problem up into a few parts.  You have the audio capture (recording), the encoding/codec, the server, and the receiving clients.

```
Capture -> Codec -> Server -> Several Clients
```

For audio capture, you will need to use the [Web Audio API along with getUserMedia](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/).  This will allow you to get 32-bit floating point PCM samples from the recording device.  This data stream takes up a ton of bandwidth... a few megabit for a stereo stream.  This stream is not directly playable in an HTML5 audio tag, and while you could play it on the receiving end with the Web Audio API, it takes up too much bandwidth to be useful.  You need to use a codec to get the bandwidth usage down.

The codecs you want to look at include MP3, AAC (and its variants such as HE-AAC), and Opus.  Not all browsers support all codecs.  MP3 is the most widely compatible but AAC provides better quality for a given bitrate.  Opus is a free and open codec but still doesn't have the greatest client adoption.  In any case, there isn't yet a codec that you can run in-browser with any real stability.  (Although it's being worked on!  There are a lot of test projects made with Emscripten.)  I solved this problem by reducing the bit depth of my samples to 16-bit signed integers and sending this PCM stream to a server to do the codec, over a binary websocket.

This encoding server took the PCM stream and ran it through a codec server-side.  Here you can use whatever you'd like, such as a licensed codec binary or a tool like FFmpeg which encapsulates multiple codecs.

Next, this server streamed the data to a real streaming media server like Icecast.  SHOUTcast and Icecast servers take the encoded stream and relay it to many clients over an HTTP-like connection.  (Icecast is HTTP compliant whereas SHOUTcast is close but not quite there which can cause compatibility issues.)

Once you have your streaming server set up, it's as simple as referencing the stream URL in your `<audio>` tag.

Hopefully that gets you started.  Depending on your needs, you might also look into WebRTC which does all of this for you but doesn't give you options for quality and also doesn't scale beyond a few users.

Comment: I know this thread is old but I wondered if this is still a valid approach. Any update?

Comment: @Chris The general approach hasn't changed much, but with MediaRecorder being more available, these days I just use that on the capture side.  You can always transcode server-side if needed.